# create a function that returns a tuple of regex expressions

Tags: python, regex, f-string

I have several different modules with similar regex expressions.
In module A, I have:

```py
string_to_find = rf'([^_A-z]{variable_name}\()(.+?)(,\s?)(.+?)(,|\))'
string_to_replace = r'\1\4\3\2\5'
```

In module B, I have:

```py
string_to_find = rf'([^_A-z]{variable_name}\()(.+?)(,\s?)(.+?)(,\s?)(.+?)(,|\))'
string_to_replace = r'\1\6\3\4\5\2\7'
```

I want to collect all these expressions into a tuple `((..,..),(..,..))` that is returned by function C in module C:

```py
def get_regex_expressions():
  regex_expressions = ((rf'([^_A-z]{variable_name}\()(.+?)(,\s?)(.+?)(,|\))', r'\1\4\3\2\5'),(rf'([^_A-z]{variable_name}\()(.+?)(,\s?)(.+?)(,\s?)(.+?)(,|\))', r'\1\6\3\4\5\2\7'))
  return regex_expressions
```

The problem is that some of them are f-strings, and 'variable_name', while defined in modules A and B, is not defined in module C.  In module A, for example, I want to be able to run `t = get_regex_expressions()` and then pass `t[0][1]`, the second expression in the first tuple, into a `re.sub` command. How do I adjust the regex_expressions so they can be stored in a tuple in a different module?  I tried putting the whole expression in double quotes, "".  This removed the error, but now I'm not sure it will be treated as a proper f-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, putting f-string expression in another set of quotes won't give you what you need.

Secondly, it seems to me that your question is an example of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). We would need to know more of "what you want to achieve" instead of "how you want to achieve it". Either way, I will attempt to answer to the extent that is possible based on the clues you provided.

Have you considered using function which takes arguments which then in turn can be used to construct your regex? Something along the lines of:

```
def get_regex_expressions(variable_name):
  regex_expressions = ((rf'([^_A-z]{variable_name}\()(.+?)(,\s?)(.+?)(,|\))', r'\1\4\3\2\5'),(rf'([^_A-z]{variable_name}\()(.+?)(,\s?)(.+?)(,\s?)(.+?)(,|\))', r'\1\6\3\4\5\2\7'))
  return regex_expressions
```

Then you can pass the variable that exists in A or B while importing the function above function from module C (assuming this is the structure you want).

Comment: that works!  thanks a lot.  if you're curious about the purpose, i'm just trying to make a function that stores a bunch of regex expressions.  'this regex expression looks for this pattern', 'that regex expression looks for this other pattern'.  some of them are complicated and the same expression is often reused in different modules, so i thought if i put all of them in a function somewhere else, i can then pull that function in any module and pick up the one i need.